# Can not seem to get examples from D3js working?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, frontend

I'm new to D3, and I'm having a little trouble getting examples from the [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) site working. For instance, here's a git gist from the site. Yet cloning the gist(https://gist.github.com/3887051), or copying the code (http://bl.ocks.org/3887051#index.html) locally to play with does not seem to run in the browser? I have written some simple d3 code which works nicely, but as d3 is entirely client-side, is there anything else I need to set up?

**[Edit]** It seems like the examples need to be served from a server due to the use of XMLHttpRequest for data. Can someone explain what this is and why its necessary, when simpler d3 code has worked without one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running the examples with Chrome and get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://.../data.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Try Firefox and the example should work. [Cross-site HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control) cause this problem.

If you want to use Chrome start the browser with `-allow-file-access-from-files`. It is not recommended though, so in the long run start your own webserver and run the code from there.